# How to back up broken device with Time Machine in Recovery Mode / Target Disk Mode?

Tags: terminal, backup, time-machine, recovery, target-disk-mode

Due to being unable to access anything but the recovery mode (and target disk mode) of my broken MacBook, I'm attempting to back up files that hadn't been backed up since my precious Time Machine backup. This includes standard files and large Virtual Machines files.

Can I use Time Machine from the Terminal in Recovery Mode to back up my files to my usual external hard drive configured with Time Machine?

Or is there any other way to efficiently back up files that were not backed up by Time Machine on the external drive? Can I use Time Machine from another OSX device to back up my broken MacBook in Target Disk Mode?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, I wouldn't backup packages installed by brew.  I would keep a list of them and install them via script to ensure only the freshest packages that I need get installed.  I use MacPorts, but the concept is the same.

Comment: I've never used TM while in Recovery (since it's a different volume that's booted).  Can you access your main volume (manually) from Recovery?

Comment: Yes, I'm in the terminal and both "Macintosh HD" and "Macintosh HD - Data" are now mounted in /Volumes.

Comment: Calling "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/usr/bin/tmutil" does not work (library not loaded), so maybe this option isn't possible. I would ideally like to find an alternative to selectively back up data as opposed to backing up the whole drive again.

Comment: I would start by going into the Data volume, then into your home folder and just copy everything to an external drive.  Since you can't run `tmutil` you're probably limited to just copying things over.

Comment: Thank you - yeah I'm trying to avoid having to back up 4 TB of data instead of ~100GB. I'll see if I can simply use rsync to back up data modified after a specific date.

Comment: The VMs should be the easiest they are all pretty much self contained within each of their respective folders.